# is Python return always necessary

Tags: python, return

I just stumbled across several python programs written by different people and I noticed that every function had a return at the end of it

```
def function01():
    # function
    # events
    # here
    return
```

I was wondering if it's good python programming practice to include return at the end of functions even if it is not returning anything (purely as a way of ending the function)

Or is it not needed and nothing different will happen in the background?

Comment: An empty `return` will return `None`. You'll get the same result if you don't use an explicit `return`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. The function returns after the last line. There is no difference between a simple `return` and no `return`.

```
def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass
    return

f = foo()
print(f)
b = bar()
print(b)
```

Output:

```
None
None
```

Comment: Note that, unlike in other languages, unadorned `return` or no return statement at all will return the _value_ `None`, not nothing. A tricky little nuance.

Comment: @imallett I wonder why they designed the language like this lol

Comment: Because of a single word: simplicity: a function simply always returns something.

Comment: Is the last expression in a function definition returned automatically? (some languages do it).